# Robot.txt disallow page but not starting with

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow specific page

> example.com/10

but not other pages starting with /10

> example.com/101
>
> example.com/102
>
> example.com/103

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Allow` keyword to achieve it:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /10*
Disallow: /10$
```

Results from http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/:

```
Url: /10
Multiple robot rules found 
Robots disallowed: All robots

Url: /101
Robots allowed: All robots

Url: /102
Robots allowed: All robots

Url: /103
Robots allowed: All robots
```

However, older robots may interpret it correctly. For example reading just the first line.

Comment: simply Disallow: /10$ works fine :)
no need for Allow: /10*

Comment: Good point. It is just for the general case. There may be for example `Disallow: /` before that.